# How to make PyCharm recognise numpy

Tags: numpy, pycharm

PyCharm does not see my numpy: thats what i got when Im trying - pip install numpy -

```
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /Users/ruslanpilipyuk/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.18.1)
```

However, when I write import numpy,as a result I got -

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

Im using mac

Comment: What interpreter is specified in File - Settings - Project - Python Interpreter? Does it have `numpy` in packages list?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you import a module, python will search for that module in some specific directories. To know which all directories it will search, use the below given code in python prompt.

```
$ import sys
$ print(sys.path)
```

If your NumPy module does not present in any of those directory, then add your NumPy module to the python search path by the following given code in python prompt.

​

```
$ import sys
$ sys.path.append("/Users/ruslanpilipyuk/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.18.1)")
$ import NumPy
```

Hope this will solve your error.

Reference: https://www.edureka.co/community/66413/import-numpy-as-np-importerror-no-module-named-numpy

Comment: just tried it, but at at the end it writes  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'NumPy' even with added path

Comment: Please check this link. It may help you. https://www.edureka.co/community/66679/import-error-no-module-named-numpy